# JSP trying to convert String to Long

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, jstl

I have a `<td>` in my jsp which has a `<spring:bind>` tag.

```
        <td>
          <spring:bind path="mailListRequest.offSeason">
            <select name="<c:out value="${status.expression}" />" id="<c:out value="${status.expression}" />">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
              <c:forEach var="t" begin="2" step="1" end="5">
                <option value="<c:out value="${t} star"/>" <c:if test="${status.value eq t}"> selected</c:if>><c:out value="${t} star"/>
                </option>
              </c:forEach>
              <option value="boutique hotels">boutique hotels</option>

            </select>
          </spring:bind>
        </td>
```

`"mailListRequest.offSeason"` is a `string` on the server side (Java). The goal here is to iterate in the `<c:forEach..>` loop variable `"t"`. Therefore the iteration will be `2,3,4,5;`and in the `<option value..>` I've made each iteration return a value with the string/word `star` in front of it therefore the output would be `2 star, 3 star, 4 star...`.

**The Issue:**
The issue is that whenever I choose one of the options in the `<c:forEach>` loop or the option `"botique hotels "` I keep getting an error in my JSP:

**Error**
`javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "test" with value "${status.value eq t}": An exception occured trying to convert String "2 star" to type "java.lang.Long" (null)`. 
Which puzzles me because `"mailListRequest.offSeason"` is set as a `string` and the values in my options are String values(I PRESUME). Perhaps it's the `<option value="<c:out value="${t} star"/>` I'm formatting wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather your select values are:

```
"1 star", "2 star", "3 star", "4 star", "5 star"
```

But then inside the `<c:forEach>` loop the values of `t` will be, in order: `1,2,3,4,5`

So your test is comparing a String `"x star"` to `t`, which is a long, and fails to convert the left operand to the type of the right operand.

You might want to create a helper variable inside the loop:

```
<c:set var="stringVal" value="${t} star" />
```

and then use that in your test:

```
<c:if test="${status.value eq stringVal}">
```